# Console prompt window appear on system("start dir") but not on system("start ipconfig")

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, visual-c++-2010

I try to create a simple UI which runs a command prompt in the background (but the windows console must not disappear) while clicking on each button, resp.

But before, I try something like `system("start dir");` to see if the button works.

Here is the problem: when I click on the left button the windows console appear and don't exit unit I close it. But this only work with `system("start dir");`. If I change **dir** to **ipconfig** (or another call-function) the windows console will appear for a second and the exit. I tried something like `system("PAUSE");` or `getch();` etc, but it doesn't work.

Why does this command work with **dir** but not with another command?

[image: Code]
[image: UI]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fundamental difference between DIR and IPCONFIG, the DIR command is built into the command processor (aka shell), IPCONFIG is a separate program stored in c:\windows\system32.

When you type START /? at the command line then you can see why it treats them differently:

```
If it is an internal cmd command or a batch file then
the command processor is run with the /K switch to cmd.exe.
This means that the window will remain after the command
has been run.

If it is not an internal cmd command or batch file then
it is a program and will run as either a windowed application
or a console application.
```

The alternative is to ask the command processor to execute the command and exit afterwards.  You do with the /c option:

```
  system("cmd.exe /c dir");
```

Or simpler yet, since system() automatically passes off the job to the command processor:

```
  system("dir");
```

Just stop using start :)

Comment: Thank you! Now I know the difference between DIR and IPCONFIG. But how can I fix my problem?

Comment: Erm, I gave specific snippets, the only possible thing you can do wrong is not trying them.

Comment: Of course, I tried system("cmd.exe /c ipconfig"); and system("ipconfig"); but the console appear for a second and then disappear.

Comment: @RaymondChen I have read his answer more than one time. Anyway, your code worked for me. Thank you. :)

Comment: @aGer it was not clear from your question whether you wanted both to pause, or you wanted neither to pause. Hans and I thought you wanted neither to pause. But the way to get both to pause was also given in Hans's answer.